# Starting a web server using C# and .net in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am using the below code to start a web server that should be open to listen always but it is executing only once, I am deploying this in AKS - the container is not staying in running state, it is exiting after completing the job i.e., printing the response.

Please help me understand where I am doing wrong or my understanding itself is not right.
May be this is not the right piece of code to use if I want the container to be always running as a web server that listens to requests from other apps in the project.

```
string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

// Start OWIN host 
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
{
    // Create HttpClient and make a request to api/values 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result;

    System.Console.WriteLine(response);
    System.Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What type of application this code is part of? this code is executed as part of Main method? Does it work on local machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen incoming `http` requests, try something like that with `HttpListener`:

```
var listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:9000/api/values");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    
    // do something here with request
    
    // default OK response
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(Array.Empty<byte>(), 0, 0);
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Also, get ensure that your firewall settings is correct, to accept  incoming requests with 9000 port

Answer (score 0):

**If your code is already working for once. Thats should be help for loop**

```
while(true){
    var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result;
System.Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried using while(true) but the response is being printed as an infinite loop. Basically, I want to deploy a Bot application in Azure Kubernetes Service and call this bot from another application.